# How can we add ''+'' two different value in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am taking value in **input** but in result i want to **add "+"** 10% in the result i.e if a person inputs 1000 and the 10% of 1000 is 100 and the total result will be 1100. I am using **"+"** but it is concatenating the value istead of adding

```js
function app() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Price</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={price}
        onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>{price + (10 / 100) * price}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can i add these two values

Comment: `<input>` values are strings , not numbers. For addition you need to convert string to number

Comment: You can try this - 
<div>{Number(price) * 1.1}</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **parseInt** for convert string to number in JavaScript. Problem in your script you are adding 2 values string and number.

```
function app() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Price</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={price}
        onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>{(parseInt(price) + (10 / 100)) * parseInt(price)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Number to avoid setting price as a String:

```js
function app(){
const [price,setPrice]=useState(0);
return(
<div>
  <label>Price</label>
  <input
  type='number'
  value={price}
  onChange={(e)=> setPrice(Number(e.target.value))}
 </div>
  {price + (10/100)*price}
/>
}
```

Beware of NaN though.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add a plus sign `+` before `e.target.value` to convert it to a number:

```
function app() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Price</label>
      <input type="number" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(+e.target.value)} />
      {price + (10 / 100) * price}
    </div>
  );
}
```